# Which Wordpress template is the related to this website?

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I am searching a Wordpress template. that would correspond best to this website :
 [Link](http://www.resultatsbaccalaureat.fr/)

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I found a lead here - "Material Design Menu in Wordpress Theme" :

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-chanCHkXO4
- http://mdlwp.com/

And this one for navigate among posts : 
 - http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-an-archives-page-in-wordpress/ 

And this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYTphLPzatE

Answer (score 0):

The [WordPress Theme Directory](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/themes/browse/popular/) and [ThemeForest](https://themeforest.net/category/wordpress), both provide free and premium themes respectively.

Whilst StackOverflow is an invaluable resource for technical Q&A, please bear in mind that future questions should be tailored to aid your research rather than getting people to do the research for you.  You will likely receive a more positive response from others, as well as more likely to get the answer you are looking for.

For example, rather than asking:

> Wich Wordpress template is the nearest to this website?

You could ask:

> Who knows of any safe and reliable WordPress Theme directories?

The former question is asking others to do the research for you, while the latter is asking people to point you in the right direction to help you undertake your research.

I hope this helps and good luck with your website!

Comment: Your answer should really be a comment to the question, as low quality questions are deleted. Or, simply ignore low quality questions, as answering the only encourages more.

Comment: My answer lies within the introduction, whereby I provide the original poster, with 2 resources to where he/she is able to look for a WordPress Theme/Template that looks like the website in question.  I am not sure how this cannot be seen as providing an answer.

Comment: I said, "Your answer should really be a comment to the question, as low quality questions are deleted." The question already has four downvotes and two close votes. It will be deleted and you've wasted your time. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: My apologies.  I misread 'Low quality questions' as 'Low quality answers'.  As I had a spare 10 minutes, I thought I would try and provide a little pointer in the hope that the original poster would improve future questions.  Hopefully, my answer was not 100% a waste of time.  Nonetheless, thank you for letting me know that poorly written questions get deleted.  I was not aware of that as I thought there would just get 'pushed to the bottom'.

Comment: Sorry but the answer is very important for me. I admit that my question is very specific but I don't want general answer, I know that there is many website that dealing about Wordpress Theme, but what I'm looking for is -as you can probably gather- is a specific Wordpress theme... However thank you for the links..